# add in object by for in in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript
I have object. When I try to add the city, it doesn't appear in the message.
This object show us the detail person. but when I want to put city (forExample)
it doesn't show in message

```
let person = {

  name: 'Sam',
  age: 30,
  employed: true,
  is_maried: false

}
```

and

```
for (let key in person){


  let massage = `key: ${key} and the value is ${person[key]}`;
  //this to give you the key name and the value in on line

  if (key in person === 'city'){

    person.city = 'NY';


  }else if (!(key in person !== 'city')){

      person.city = 'UK';

  }

console.log(massage);
}
```

Comment: I've no idea what you are trying to achieve here but `key in person` evaluates as a boolean so will never equal a string

Comment: Another issue: distinguish between `person.city` and `person["city"]`. I've got a feeling you meant the latter.

Comment: Yes, that what i want git it

Comment: I read when I want to add city, we well use Method push to add the object

Comment: also I read about how to add to object and it was simple just `person.city = "Uk";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let person = {
  name: 'Sam',
  age: 30,
  employed: true,
  is_maried: false
}

if (person.city) {
  person.city = "NY";
} else {
  person.city = "UK";
}

console.log(person);
```